# Is it possible to get a word/txt doc from Android Studio, and then manipulate the data?

Tags: android, file-upload

I'm wondering is it possible to get a txt/word document from a user which the application can then read the contents of said file.

For example, The application gets the file "sample.doc" from the user. Inside this is file is simply "1,2,3,4". Can the application read the file and then have a method where if the file contains the int 2, print "The file contains the number 2"?
Is this possible?

Comment: What does it mean to "upload" something from a computer programming tool (Android Studio)? Where do you want to "upload" this file to? Who or what is "I" in "I can then read the text"? What does "make methods based off the contents" mean?

Comment: My bad, I've worded this wrong. I'll edit it

Comment: What does "gets the file" mean? Do you mean that the user chooses a file on their device?

Comment: Yes. I'm unsure if I would have to store the file somewhere to have the app access it or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, let's take this in pieces:

#### Can a device have files?

Yes. For example, a user can plug their device to their desktop or notebook using a USB cable and transfer over files. Or they can download a file on their device from a Web browser on that device. And so on.

#### Can an app ask the user to choose a file on their device?

Yes. There are [many libraries that allow you to prompt the user to choose a file](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/35). You can also use some stuff built into the Android SDK (`ACTION_GET_CONTENT` or `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`), which give your users more flexibility, but are a bit more complex for you to implement.

#### Can an app read data from a file?

Yes... if the file is in a file format that your app knows how to read. Plain text files are easy. Word documents would require a third-party library.

#### Can an app display information on the screen, such as "The file contains the number 2"?

Yes.